# Have to call alert for rest JS to run on Iphone (safari)

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, local-storage, alert

I'm having trouble with JS code not executing on iPhone if I don't call `alert` before `if` statement. This is my code:

```
submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var dataFromForm = $("#send").serialize();
  alert(); // Without this the code below wont execute on iphne
  if (window.localStorage) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("timeout")) {
      const timePrev = localStorage.getItem("timeout");
      const timeNow = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
      if (timeNow - timePrev >= 300) {
        var available = true;
      } else {
        var available = false;
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
          '<span class="fail"> Spam protection</span>';
      }
    } else {
      var available = true;
    }
  } else {
    var available = true;
  }
  if (available) {
    $.post("mail.php", dataFromForm, function (data) {
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";

      console.log(data);
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(data);
      if (data.statusBool === true) {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
          '<span class="success">' + data.status + "</span>";
        document.getElementById("name").value = "";
        document.getElementById("email").value = "";
        document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
        var timenow = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        localStorage.setItem("timeout", timenow);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML =
          '<span class="fail">' + data.status + "</span>";
      }
    });
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "";
  }, 3000);
};
```

code below `alert`  doesn't execute if I don't put `alert` before that statement.

Does anyone know how to solve this, or have an idea of what could I use instead of alert, so it's not visible for the user?

Comment: If you omit the `alert()`, is there an error message in the console? In my experience, this is usually some sort of timing issue. What is happening before this section of code? Are you waiting on something else to happen?

Comment: Well on iPhone there is no way to display console and there is nothing happening before, code is executed upon form submit.

Comment: Does it work if you wrap both `if` statements in a `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and remove the `alert`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon no it doesn't

Comment: This might be a scope issue; try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rqht1kzo/ (minus the first line obviously)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks, your version works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by [@Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

[jsfiddle.net/rqht1kzo](http://%20jsfiddle.net/rqht1kzo)

```
localStorage.setItem('timeout', new Date().getTime() / 1000 - 400);

var available = false;
const timePrev = window.localStorage && window.localStorage.getItem('timeout');
if (timePrev) {
  const timeNow = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  if (timeNow - timePrev >= 300) available = true;
}

if (available) {
  console.log("it's available")
} else {
  document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '<span class="fail"> fail message</span>';
}
```